# Ants and their love for sweet and sugar

Tags: zoology, sugar

I have observed many times that ants are able to reach the box where sweet items are kept even if the box is kept in secret.
How do they identify it??

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! We encourage you to do some research on your own and then, informed by what you have learned, ask any questions you still have (ideally with references to reliable sources). At very least please search on this site for before posting — there are several related questions with decent answers present.——— Please also take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and either delete or [edit] your question accordingly. Thanks! 